# accessing vue.prototype from component level

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So in my `main.js` file, I have the following set:

```
Vue.prototype.api_url = 'http://localhost'
```

and in one of my components: `dashboard.vue`

I am using the `beforeRouteEnter`

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
    }
},
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    axios.post(this.api_url + '/dashboard')
}}}
```

However, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'api_url' of undefined`

On another component where I'm not using the beforeRouteEnter, I am able to access this.api_url without using an import statement at the component level.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In general, to avoid conflict, you need to define and use it with a dollar sign $:

```
Vue.prototype.$api_url = 'http://localhost'
```

and

```
axios.post(this.$api_url + '/dashboard')
```

**UPDATE**

As explained [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards), inside beforeRouteEnter you don't have access to this because the component isn't created yet.

> ```
>   beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
>     // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
>     // does NOT have access to `this` component instance,
>     // because it has not been created yet when this guard is called!   },
> ```

To access this, you can pass a callback inside `next()` function, like this:

```
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        next(that => {
            console.log(that.$api_url );
        })
    }
```

**Update II**

as for Sphinx comment down here,

> you can import Vue in your dashboard.vue, then directly access
> Vue.prototype.$api_url

and that will work too, before the component actually mounts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: facing: TypeError: Cannot read property '$api_url' of undefined

Comment: Nice :) . Where beforeRouteEnter is placed in your component? Inside a method?

Comment: `this` is not yet defined in beforeRouteEnter. use `vm.$api_url` to access it

Comment: vm isnt defined either, before next(vm =>{

Comment: updated so you can see where the beforeRouteEnter is placed

Comment: Thanks for the head up guys. I updated my answer. My guess, now is, will it work without this at all? Just by calling $api_url ?

Comment: Let me try to recreate this situation.

Comment: sure let me know what else i can send to help

Comment: my problem is that im using axios to determine if the user should have access to the page or not (200 vs. 401). So I need the api_url route in order to be able to call the api to get that status code. If i import the api_url path into the component, then i can access api_url, but i dont wan to have to import this to every component if possible

Comment: In this case I would use an interceptor for axios. Do a search here or google it, its the best way to handle logins. You can set that based on the response it sends the user to a route for example. 
However, more in general, this question is solved, so please mark it as it.

Comment: import Vue in your dashboard.vue, then directly access `Vue.prototype.$api_url`

Comment: Nice! But would you use this solution in all of your components that needs authentication?

Comment: why not? or another way is use global navigation guard=`beforeEach` in main.js, then we can directly access `Vue.prototype.$api_url` or `app.$api_url` (app is the Vue instance) at there.

Comment: I definitively usually go for the guard, considering usually most of the routes are protected and few public, makes more sense. But obviously depends from the purpose of the app